# When is a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism smoothable?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose I have a smooth Riemannian manifold $X$ with induced distance function $d$, and a bi-Lipschitz (with respect to $d$) homeomorphism
$$\phi: X \to X.$$

Under what circumstances could $\phi$ be smoothable to a diffeomorphism? By "smoothable" in this case I mean "homotopic to a diffeomorphism through bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms" (this might not be standard, I suppose). Are there any clear obstructions?

Comment: What do you mean by "smoothable"?

Comment: @Igor Belegradek: I guess the OP means "approximated by $C^1$ diffeomorphisms", with uniform convergence?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question to make it more clear what I mean!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any self-homeomorphism of a manifold of dimension $\neq 4$ is topologically isotopic to a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism, see lemma 2.4 in [Lipschitz and quasiconformal approximation of homeomorphism pairs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864199001455)
by Jouni Luukkainen.

There are exotic spheres (e.g. in dimension $7$) that admit a self-homeomorphism that is not homotopic to a diffeomorphism, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/348603/1573). This gives a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism that is not homotopic to a diffeomorphism.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. Is there a counterexample in dimension 4? Perhaps one can appeal to Donaldson-Sullivans work on Lipschitz/quasi-conformal 4-manifolds...

Comment: @RohilPrasad: I do not know what happens in dimension 4. You now have all the references that I have, and should be able to explore it further.

Comment: I am not sure if the answer is correct. The link shows a self-homeomorphis, that is not isotopic to a diffeomorphism. This is because the manifold with reversed orientation are not diffeomorphic. I think the homeomorphism cannot be bi-Lipschitz due to uniqueness of the Lipschitz structure in dimensions $\neq 4$.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: I do not claim to understand Luukkainen's paper, but I think what I say is a formal consequence of his Lemma 2.4 for $A=\emptyset$ and $B=M$.

Comment: I am sorry, I was stupid. Exotic spheres are bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic exactly for a reason I mentioned: uniqueness of a Lipschitz structure.

Answer (score 3):

There is some interest in a related question in non-linear elasticity, specifically people there would consider a function "smoothable" if there is a close-by (in some norm applying both to function and its inverse) diffeomorphism.

In 2D there are some results with regards to this, see e.g. [Smooth approximation of bi-Lipschitz orientation-preserving homeomorphisms](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPC_2014__31_3_567_0/) by Danieri & Pratelli, who prove that there is a close diffeomorphism in some bi-Sobolev norm for domains in the plane (which if I am not mistaken should imply the same result at least for compact manifolds). But the proof uses a bi-Lipschitz extension theorem, so I am not sure if one can construct homotopies from that result easily and there seems to be no way to extend this to higher dimensions.